# mysql case in update statement with REPLACE

Tags: mysql, replace, case, sql-update

I currently have something like this:

```
UPDATE table1  SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'abc', 'abc1') WHERE column1 LIKE '%abc%';
UPDATE table1  SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'def', 'def1') WHERE column1 LIKE '%def%';
```

I am trying to consolidate these into a single update statement and am trying the following:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = 
CASE
WHEN column1 LIKE '%abc%' THEN REPLACE(column1, 'abc', 'abc1')
WHEN column1 LIKE '%def%' THEN REPLACE(column1, 'def', 'def1')
ELSE column1
END;
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? I am new to case/when. Thanks!

Comment: Overall the functionality that you're using is very slow. `LIKE` is slower than `MATCH ... AGAINST`, which is slower than comparison of equality. `CASE WHEN` is also slow. That being said - if you have a large table that is accessed all the time, then 2 UPDATEs may be more convenient because the table will be on lockdown less time.

Comment: Why do you want to consolidate the 2 update statements? I would think you'll be better off doing it as 2 updates

Comment: the issue is there are more like 20 statements at the moment, I just put in 2 for the sake of simplicity. Is it still better just to leave all of the individual statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `LIKE '%abc%'`, the update statement will require a full table scan. In that case, combining the two statements will improve overall performance. However, in your suggestion, every single row is updated and most of them are updated without being changed (column1 value is replaced with column1 value).

You want to make sure that you keep the `WHERE` clause so that only rows that really need change are changed. This unnecessary write to disk is slower than checking whether the row matches the criteria.

Do this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = 
CASE
WHEN column1 LIKE '%abc%' THEN REPLACE(column1, 'abc', 'abc1')
WHEN column1 LIKE '%def%' THEN REPLACE(column1, 'def', 'def1')
END
WHERE column1 LIKE '%abc%' OR column1 LIKE '%def%';
```

Comment: oh right, i totally forgot to include the where in my post (i do have that in my code!)

Comment: another question regarding that though: this will only work if all of the initial update statements are mutually exclusive to begin with right? (ie no row meets more than one LIKE condition and therefore each row only gets updated a maximum of one time)

Comment: @lolcat: that's correct. If there is a row that matches more than one LIKE condition, it will only get one update, the first CASE that matches. For example, if you had a value of "abcdef", it would be updated to "abc1def", not "abc1def1".