# Use Replace Clause in Insert Stataement for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, replace, insert

I am using MySQL database. I want to insert data into it. But one column data contains `special characters`. (backslash) I want to replace it with `Double backslash` and then execute Insert query.

Can we do it using Insert Query?

While looking for the answer I came across

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '/', '//')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%articles/updates/%'
```

So it is possible use  `Replace` in Update query.

Can we do the same in insert query? Please Let me know if you can help me.

Comment: Did you try running the query?? Are you getting any error? As it should work without any error

Comment: Yes we can use 'REPLACE' in update query..                        for more example you can see following link                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216605/mysql-case-in-update-statement-with-replace

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
REPLACE INTO table_name(column_name1,column_name2,…)
VALUES(value1,value2,…)
```

More info from:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on your table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT 
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.col_name = IF(NEW.col_name = '/','//',NEW.col_name);
```